# How can I connect to remote SQL Server instance running in a Docker Container?

Tags: sql-server, docker

So, here is my situation: I have a MacBook Pro with a SQL Server instance running inside of a docker container. Here are some of the settings and stuff that I have verified:

The server is definitely up and running, and I am able to connect to it locally.

The docker container maps port 1433/TCP to port 1433 of the MacBook Pro.

Here is the output of docker ps (I have other containers running, but ignore those -- there are no overlaps in the ports):

```
1270c6cfd9ac   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-CU8-ubuntu   "/opt/mssql/bin/sqls…"   4 months ago    Up 5 hours   1433/tcp                                                   bp_sqlserver
```

I obtained this via the docker command:

```
docker run --name bp_sqlserver --network=cynet -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e SA_PASSWORD='*******' -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-CU8-ubuntu
```

[EDIT: .... The error was in the docker run operation. I neglected to specify the port-binding -p 1433:1433. Credit to @AlwaysLearning for asking for this information].

I have (temporarily) disabled the firewall on my MacBook Pro.

I have verified that the server is configured to allow remote connections.

I have a separate Windows machine where I have installed both sqlcmd and MSSMS.
I am using SQLServer Authentication, since many of my tools are not going to be Windows-friendly (as opposed to doing Windows Auth).

My house, where I am doing this from uses a single router with dynamic IP assignment via WiFi. I found the IP assigned by the WiFi, and I have determined that I can ping my Macbook Pro from my Windows machine.

I also found that tracert from the Windows machine to the MacbookPro shows something reasonable.

For the sake of argument, let us pretend that that IP address is 1.2.3.4.

Now, when I invoke sqlcmd:

```
C:\Users\Bill>sqlcmd -S 1.2.3.4,1433 -U testuser -P notapassword -d testdb
```

What I get is:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: The wait operation timed out..

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..

I get a similar result using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). I will worry about getting SSMS working after I get a basic sqlcmd invocation working.

What might I be missing?

Comment: Have you confirmed via the few steps in these instructions that the SQL instance is definitely up and working locally?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-linux-ver15&preserve-view=true&pivots=cs1-bash#pullandrun2019  (I know some of the commands noted in the instructions are Linux specific, but hopefully you'll know the comparable Mac commands)

Comment: I verified that the docker image is up and running. Also, I can connect to it locally from my MacBook and run queries.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the publish parameters (`-p` or `--publish`) from your docker run line. It sounds like you may be binding to the host's `localhost` address instead of its assigned/public IP address.

Comment: Thanks, @AlwaysLearning. It looks like I may have forgotten to actually make port 1433 visible outside of the container -- or the network of containers sharing the same bridge. I will retry with that.